# PHP Hyperlink / Fetch a single record from SQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

After researching over and over, (perhaps I am not asking the right question) I am at my wit's end. What I am trying to do is to connect a DB with a page. The page simply collects all of the employee records, and then lists them as hyperlinks. This part I figured out. However, I cannot get the link to produce what I need.

At that point, there should be a listing of all of the attributes of THAT RECORD only. In other words, when you click on 'Mary Smith', everything disappears, and then a record for just her appears - showing name, ID, etc.....

```
?php
$db = new SQLite3('MicroUniversity.db3');
echo "<fieldset style='width: 450px'>";
echo "<h2>Listing Employees</h3>";
$results = $db->query('SELECT * from EMPLOYEE ORDER BY EMP_LNAME');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()){
    $strName = $row['EMP_LNAME'].", ".$row['EMP_FNAME'] . "," . $row['EMP_NUM'];
    //$strLink = "<a href = 'person.php? = " . $row['EMP_NUM'] . "'>" . $strName . "</a>";
    $strLink = "<a href =?func=true" . $row['EMP_NUM'] . "'>" . $strName . "</a>";
    echo "<li>".$strLink."</li>";       
}
    echo"</fieldset>";
?>
```

Comment: Quote the attribute value. Your first commented out link has the `href` quoted correctly. Also you should encode the `emp_num` unless you know what will always be a number.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to reload the page with some $_GET-Parameter when you want to request one person only and thatwhy you need to generate links of every person available. (?)

```
SELECT * from EMPLOYEE ORDER BY EMP_LNAME
```

outputs all the employees.

You could just put some filter within your While(..){ ... } and then output everything on the actual person.

```
if($_GET['person'] == $row['EMP_NUM']){
 echo 'details ...';
 print_r($row);
}else{
 echo '<BR><a href="person.php?person='.$row['EMP_NUM'].'">Link for: '.$row['EMP_FNAME'].' '.$row['EMP_LNAME'].'</a>';
}
```

This is probably a working thing but not the nicest. You might then improve it or start another SQL-Query to output the details. But as you not put any unfiltered $_GET-strings into your SQL-String this is at least save to use.

**NOTE:** I think your filename is person.php. Otherwise change it! And this is not with any style, thats your work :)